# Incrementing a global static int in main

Tags: c, static

Here's my code:

File DataTypes.h

```
static int count=0;
```

File TreeOps.h

```
#include"DataTypes.h"
void printTree(Tree* ptr)
```

File TreeOps.c

```
#include"TreeOps.h"
void printTree(pointer){
count++;  // incrementing the count;
printf("%d",counter);
}
```

File TreeMain.c

```
#include"TreeOps.h"
printTree(pointer); // all the necessary declarations are done.
printf("%d",count);
```

If in printTree function the `printf` gives count=1; while in main function it gives me 0.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

static variable in this context means: every c file has its own variable instance. Remove static definition in h-file:

```
extern int count;
```

and add this to one of c files:

```
int count = 0;
```

extern means: this is forward declaration. By defining a variable as extern, you tell to compiler that count has int type, and this variable is created somewhere. Actually, this variable is created in one and only one c file. You can use it in any c file where  DataTypes.h is included. In the file where this variable is created, compiler uses it. In all other file this variable becomes external reference, which is resolved later by linker.

Comment: why do i need to write `int count=0` in .c file.. doesnt making it extern at the first place makes it availablt to every other file?
Also whic .c file shall i define it in? main.c or TreeOps.c?

Comment: so shall i remove the static definition from DataTypes.h adn in PLACE of that i write  `extern int count;`
Now in my main.c i write

    #include"DataTypes.h"
    int count=0;
    void main()
    {
    printTree(pointer);
    printf("count");
    } 

will it give me the right answer.. because it is not?
it still does not increment the count?

Comment: i had to make a new file `new.h` and define extern int count there, and then i had to include it in both the .c files
Does not it automatically take DataTypes.h from the TreeOps.h?

Because it wasnt wrking before, but now it is.

Comment: Handling #include lines, rrecompiler adds all h-files to the beginning of c files, and then compiler works with them. If your program works, this means, the final result is as in my answer. Variable is declared (with extern) in several c files, and created only in one of them.

Answer (score 1):

First off, *defining* data or functions in header files is a bad practice in C programming. In `DataTypes.h` you don't just *declare* the `count` variable, but you *define* it.

What actually happens is that the `count` is defined separately in each translation unit and you end up with two variables after linking. The linker doesn't merge them because they are marked `static`, that means they should be local to the translation unit.

If you want the `count` variable to be shared between the `TreeOps.c` and `TreeMain.c` translation units, you must use `extern` in the header file which only declares it:

```
extern int count;
```

And then define it globally as `int count` in either of `TreeOps.c` or `TreeMain.c`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "global static int" in your program. Entities declared as `static` cannot possibly be "global". The whole point of declaring something `static` is to make it *local* to a specific translation unit. This is exactly what you've done: you have declared two completely independent static variables in two different translation units. Each variable is local to its own translation unit. Then you are modifying one of these variables and printing the other. No wonder that the other remains unchanged.

In this case you have to decide what it is exactly you want. You can either have your variable as a global variable or as a static variable, but not both at the same time. "Global variable" and "static variable" are mutually exclusive concepts. So, what is it you want: global or static?

Comment: what if i want to do something like this. i want to have a global type of variable(available to all the files and functions), that if i modify in one of the function in any file, it gets affected in the rest too?

Comment: @Karan: declare the variable as `extern int count` in one header file, then include that header file in each of the source files and have `int count` defined globally in one of the source files. The linker will do its job then.

Comment: @Karan: In that case you need a *global* variable. Other answers already provided you with the proper set of declarations.